# Android Twitter Login button not working "unable to complete the action"

Tags: java, android, api, twitter

I used the Twitter sdk for this android app. 
It is possible to press on the twitter button, but after it trying to connect to Twitter, i got a short Toast "unable to complete the action"

I did completely what the twitter dev page told me (https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter)

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Twitter.initialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.tw__login_btn_txt), getString(R.string.tw__max_tweet_chars)))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });


    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.

        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }



    }
```

and the error:

Authorization completed with an error

> com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
>                                                                               at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:98)
>                                                                               at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:171)
>                                                                               at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:130)
>                                                                               at
>   com.twitter.ratz.william.test.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:64)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7022)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4253)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4300)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1588)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6321)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 1):

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
    .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
    .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key), getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret)))
    .debug(true)
    .build();

twitter.initialize(config);

setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

Comment: first twitter initialize after add setContentView

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing Twitter twice, one before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and the other after.

Your code should look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Twitter.initialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.

        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
}
```

or like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.tw__login_btn_txt), getString(R.string.tw__max_tweet_chars)))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
    }
}
```